# Como ingresar valores a un array con la llave en php?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo el *array(0)* en `data tiene {3:1.30}` lo que quiero hacer es llenar las *posiciones (0,1,2)* con el valor de 0. Es decir que quede en data `{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:1.30}`.
Por ejemplo el *array(1)* en `data tiene {0:0.31,2:0.74,3:0.69}` lo que quiero hacer es llenar las posiciones (1) con el valor de 0. Es decir que quede en data `{0:0.31,1:0,2:0.74,3:0.69}`.

Lo que hice fue esto pero no sale nada, no agrega los valores queda igual

```
foreach ($causales as $row_causales){
    foreach ($row_causales['data'] as $key => $row_data ){
        for ($j=0;$j<=3;$j++){
            if($i!==$key){
                $causales[$i]['data'][$j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas recorrer el array `data`.  Puedes hacerlo con el for interno de 0 a 3 y chequear si los valores existen en las llaves de `data` usando `array_keys` y `in_array`.  Tambien necesitas agregar `&` a la variable `$row_causales` para poder editar los valores.  Quedaria algo asi:

```
foreach ($causales as &$row_causales){
    $keys = array_keys($row_causales['data']);
    for ($j=0;$j<=3;$j++){
        if(!in_array($j,$keys)){
             $row_causales['data'][$j] = 0;
        }         
    }
    ksort($row_causales['data']);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta si funciono, pero los agrega al final. es decir queda algo así {3:0.69.  , 0:0 , 1:0 , 2:0}. existe alguna forma de ordenar los indices?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  Puedes usar `ksort`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo. espero ayudarte en otra oportunidad saludos